# JS caret to selection by pressing button in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a caret in the textarea (no selection). I need to make selection out of it **by pressing a button**.
For example: "This is a te|xt"

```
var range = document.selection.createRange ();
range.moveEnd('character');
range.select();
alert (range.htmlText);
```

But when I press button, the text on the button is being selected, not in the text field.
Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: it does not matter is it button or not. When you click,  document.selection.createRange () changes. But it is does not change if there is any selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOCUS to textfield is answer